# Add trailing word to a specific line in file

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, files

I have a file contains many lines like this for example

```
AAA ATAGSGSGS
BBB Thhahahahahs
CCC lmmmmm
DDD GAGAGAGAGA

AAA IIIII
BBB OOOO
CCC YYYYY
```

...and so on

I want to add specific word i the end of all the lines that starts with CCC.

For example. I want to add the word 'smile', so the result will be

```
AAA ATAGSGSGS
BBB Thhahahahahs
CCC lmmmmm smile
DDD GAGAGAGAGA

AAA IIIII
BBB OOOO
CCC YYYYY smile
```

Can you tell me please how can do that ?

Comment: This is trivial with `sed`; what have you searched for and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

`sed -i.backup '/^CCC/s/$/ smile/' data.txt`

Explore of this sed command and program:

1. `sed -i.backup` In place mode -- edit input file and (optionally) backup original file with suffix (`.backup`).
2. `/^CCC/` Regular expression to find -- string begined (`^`) with CCC.
3. `s/$/ smile/` Search end of string(`s/$/`) and replace it with smile (`smile/`).

Comment: Actually i want to add /1 when i try to ru the command it shows this error msg  sed: -e expression n°1, caractère 14: option inconnue pour `s'

Comment: maybe because of / before 1 (/1)

Comment: @MejaitAnouar Yes, you must use slash (```\```) for escaping: `\/1`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `,` or `|` instead of `/` as separator character in the `sed` command, then escaping the `/` in your replacement text will be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -E 's/^(CCC.+)/\1 smile/' <data.in >data.out
```

You can also edit in place:

```
sed -i -E 's/^(CCC.+)/\1 smile/' data.dat
```